# Generate parser that runs a received parser on the output of another parser and monadically joins the results

Tags: parsing, haskell, monads, monad-transformers, parsec

given the following type and function, meant to parse a field of a CSV field into a string:

```
type Parser resultType = ParsecT String () Identity resultType
cell :: Parser String
```

I have implemented the following function:

```
customCell :: String -> Parser res  -> Parser res
customCell typeName subparser = 
  cell
    >>= either (const $ unexpected typeName) 
               return . parse (subparser <* eof) ""
```

Though I cannot stop thinking that I am not using the Monad concept as much as desired and that eventually there is a better way to merge the result of the inner with the outer parser, specially on what regards its failure.

Does anybody know how could I do so, or is this code what is meant to be done?

PS - I now realised that my type simplification is probably not appropriate and that maybe what I want is to replace the underlying Identity Monad by the Either Monad.... Unfortunately, I do not feel enough acquainted with monad transformers yet.

PS2 - What the hell is the underlying monad good for anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elaborating on @Daniel Wagner's answer...  The way parsers are normally built with Parsec, you start with low-level parsers that parse specific characters (e.g., a plus sign or a digit), and you build parsers on top of them using combinators (like a `many1` combinator that turns a parser that reads a single digit into a parser that reads one or more digits, or a monadic parse that parsers "one or more digits" followed by a "plus sign" followed by "one or more digits").

However, each parser, whether it's a low-level digit parser or a higher-level "addition expression" parser, is intended to be applied directly to the same input stream.

What you don't *typically* do is write a parser that gobbles a chunk of the input stream to produce, say, a `String` and another parser that parses that *`String`* (instead of the original input stream) and try to combine them.  This is the kind of "vertical composition" that isn't directly supported by Parsec and looks unnatural and non-monadic.

As pointed out in the comments, there are *some* situations where vertical composition is the cleanest overall approach (like when you have one language embedded within the components or expressions of another language), but it's not the usual approach taken by a Parsec parser.

The bottom line in your application is that a `cell` parser that produces only a `String` is too specialized to be useful.  A more useful Parsec framework for CSV files would be:

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String

-- | `csv cell` parses a CSV file each of whose elements is parsed by `cell`
csv :: Parser a -> Parser [[a]]
csv cell = many (row cell)

-- | `row cell` parses a newline-terminated row of comma separated
--   `cell`-expressions
row :: Parser a -> Parser [a]
row cell = sepBy cell (char ',') <* char '\n'
```

Now, you can write a custom cell parser that parses positive integers:

```
customCell :: Parser Int
customCell = read <$> many1 digit
```

and parse CSV files:

```
> parse (csv customCell) "" "1,2,3\n4,5,6\n"
Right [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>
```

Here, instead of having a `cell` subparser that explicitly parses a comma-delimited cell into a string to be fed to a different parser, the "cell" is an implicit context in which a supplied cell parser is called to parse the underlying input stream at the appropriate point where one would expect a comma-delimited cell in the middle of a row in the middle of the input stream.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly I know of no parser library or parser generator for Haskell that supports vertical parser composition like this. Something like what you wrote is about as good as it gets. Dang!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by vertical parser composition. Do you mind expanding a bit?

Comment: @gallais I mean the operation you're asking for: a way to take a `Parser Foo [Bar]` and a `Parser Bar Baz` and turn it into a `Parser Foo Baz`.

Comment: Oh I see. With simple types like these the goal is much clearer than in OP's question I think. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I wrote a parser library that supports vertical composition `https://github.com/quickdudley/phaser`