# Parse Within Parse - Attoparsec

Tags: parsing, haskell

Assume I want to break lines up with attoparsec, then parse the line contents. Is there a way to apply another parser to a `Parser Text,` or do I need to apply `parseOnly`?

e.g. say I have:

```
import qualified Data.Attoparsec.Text as A
import Data.Attoparsec.Text (Parser)
import Data.Text  (Text)

wordList :: Parser [String]
wordList = A.sepBy (A.many1 A.letter) (A.char ' ')
anyLine :: Parser Text
anyLine = A.takeTill A.isEndOfLine <* A.endOfLine
```

Is there some way to do `wList <$> anyLine`? I'm trying to use takeTill as it's very fast.

Comment: [Possible duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46186238/791604)

Comment: Ergo this is a bad idea?

Comment: @DanielWagner, I concur. Carbon, well, usually, but there are some situations where you do want that. I believe that's the idea behind [Codec.CBOR.FlatTerm](https://github.com/well-typed/cborg/blob/master/cborg/src/Codec/CBOR/FlatTerm.hs), but I could be remembering wrong.